# Duplicate Symbol Linker Error (C++ help)

Tags: c++, linker, constraint-programming

I'm learning some CSP (constraint satisfaction) theory stuff right now, and am using [this](http://www.cril.univ-artois.fr/~roussel/CSP-XML-parser/) library to parse XML files. I'm using Xcode as an IDE.

My program compiles fine, but when it goes to link the files, I get a duplicate symbol error with the XMLParser_libxml2.hh file. My files are separated as such:

A class header file that includes the XMLParser file above
A class implementation file that include the class header file
A main file that includes the class header file

The duplicate symbol is occurring in main.o and classfile.o, but as far as I can tell, I'm not actually adding that .hh file twice.

Full error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol bool CSPXMLParser::UTF8String::to<std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::basic_string<char,
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) constin
/Users/vash265/CSP/Untitled/build/Untitled.build/Debug/Untitled.build/Objects-
normal/x86_64/dStructFill.o and
/Users/vash265/CSP/Untitled/build/Untitled.build/Debug/Untitled.build/Objects-
normal/x86_64/main.o`
```

Copying the implementation of the class into the main file and taking the class implementation file out of the compilation target removes the error, but it's a disorganized mess this way, and I'll be adding more classes very soon (and it would be nice to have them in separate files).

As I've come to understand it, this is caused by the file (XMLParser_libxml2.hh) having both the class and function definition and implementation in one file (and it seems as though this might have been necessary due to the use of templates in that 'header' file).  Any ideas on how to get around sticking all my class files in my main.cpp?  (I've tried `#ifdefs`, they don't work).

Comment: Are all of the functions (except member functions defined within a class definition or function templates) in the header declared `inline`?

Comment: we would need more details on how your code is structured and need to know if the classes generating the duplicate symbols errors are written by you or already exist.  Basically though this means that you are trying to link you code twice.  It does however sound like a issue I had once and this was due to the way I was building my app ie I was using a mix of static and dynamic linking.  So make sure you link everything static or everything dynamic.  To have a mix of both is complicated and I didn't go into that

Comment: @James

If the you're referring to the header file that was provided in the link, then I believe all of the functions are member functions of a class.  It's a bit hard to tell as the code is kind of a mess.  As far as my own code goes, I don't have any functions that aren't member functions.  



@Yan

The files generating the errors are ultimately created by me.  The error arose from including the XMLParser header (not written by me) in my class header file, which in turn was included in the main function and class implementation files (which I wrote, and are the files named in the error).

Answer (score 3):

James was correct.  The three template functions inside the header file needed to be declared inline for it to link properly.  Thanks!