# Mocking a c file in production codebase cppUnit

Tags: c, mocking, cppunit

I am running cppUnit in OSX
production code is compiled into library, and test/mocks are compiled into objets.
When I try to mock an external function that is not in the production code, everything works fine.
When I try to mock function Bar() in foo.c with a Bar() in foo_mocks.c I get
Linking MyProductTests_tests
duplicate symbol _Bar in:
    objs/test/mocks/foo_mocks.o
    lib/libMyProductTests.a(foo.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I confirmed that foo_mocks.h has

## include "foo.h"

I cannot find any guidance on where to look next.

Comment: It's hard to say without more information (eg, what's in foo.h), but have a look at the answers to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116188/understanding-the-origin-of-a-linker-duplicate-symbol-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function Pointer substitution is required in this case.