# Apple Mach-O Linker error, duplicate symbol note: there is no '.m' file imported

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I have an issue with weird error which appeared suddenly (or at least I can't recall anything I've made for this issue to appear), the error list looks like this:

> duplicate symbol _NSStringFromMargin in:
>       /Users/...-ehsqzpjjajyzdnevdhqhhsgeqhre/Build/Intermediates/ABC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CSFilterStrip.o
>       /Users/...-ehsqzpjjajyzdnevdhqhhsgeqhre/Build/Intermediates/ABC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABC.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CSMainMenuVC.o
>
> ...
>
> ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

All 6 about the same NSStringFromMargin and always first line points to `CSFilterStrip.o` location, I can't figure it out why this is happening, below is the `Margin.h`

```
//Margin.h
#ifndef ABC_Margin_h
#define ABC_Margin_h

struct Margin {
    int left;
    int top;
    int right;
    int bottom;
};
typedef struct Margin Margin;

CG_INLINE Margin
MarginMake(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
{
    Margin margin;

    margin.left = left;
    margin.top = top;
    margin.right = right;
    margin.bottom = bottom;

    return margin;
}
NSString *NSStringFromMargin(Margin margin)
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%d,%d,%d,%d}",margin.left,margin.top,margin.right,margin.bottom];
}

#endif
```

In the CSFilterStrip.h i'm importing Margin.h because of this:

```
@property (nonatomic) Margin margin;
```

Without this import I have: "Interface type cannot be statically allocated" error, I could add * but why then there is no need for pointer when using CGRect after which I've made Margin object.

And just to reiterate: I've checked and there is no "*.m" imported accidentally.

**Update**
As diagnosed by [@Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754705/michael) I moved offensive method from header to separate category designed for Margin: NSString+MarginUtils, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you are defining `NSStringFromMargin` in your header file. Instead, you should just declare it in your header file, and define it in your .m file.

**.h should be:**

```
NSString *NSStringFromMargin(Margin margin);
```

**.m should be:**

```
NSString *NSStringFromMargin(Margin margin)
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%d,%d,%d,%d}",margin.left,margin.top,margin.right,margin.bottom];
}
```

See also [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116594/754705).

Comment: Can you help me with that? I've created Margin.h similar to CGGeometry.h, do I create Margin.m with @implementation only?

Comment: or I just remove this utility method into some category e.g. NSString(MarginHelper) ?