# Duplicate Symbols in object files:

Tags: c++, r, compilation, linker-errors

I am trying to compile two .cpp files, (foo.cpp and bar.cpp) and build a shared object (project.so). But the compilation fails and (a part of) the error I am getting is:

```
....
duplicate symbol _n in:
foo.o
bar.o
ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to see 
invocation)
make: *** [project.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘project’
```

My .cpp files have few common and uncommon header files, a few commonly and uncommonly named functions, and a set of commonly named variables:

> **foo.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

size_t m1;
double k1=2.0;
std::vector<double> x,y;
std::vector<double> z;
size_t n,p;

void inputfoo(){...}
void output(){...}
```

> **bar.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "Eigen/Cholesky"

size_t m2;
double k2=2.0;
std::vector<double> x,y;
std::vector<double> z;
size_t n,p;

void inputbar(){...}
void output(){...}
```

My attempt:

I am able to get lesser number of 'duplicate symbols' error if I differ the names of global variables in each .cpp files. That is, if I change the `size_t m` to `size_t m1` in foo.cpp and `size_t m2` in bar.cpp, i do not get this part in the error

```
duplicate symbol _m in:
    foo.o
    bar.o
```

So, now I can see that the 5 symbols in the errors are for x,y,z,n,p ( defined globally in each .cpp file)

Same goes if I differ the name of the commonly named functions. Previously, I would also get this part in the error,

```
duplicate symbol __Z4inputP4init3RNGPi in:
    foo.o
    bar.o
```

which directs me to the input(){...} function.

So, I changed the name of one of the commonly named function ( input (){..} ), to `inputfoo` and `inputbar` and the respective error went away.

Now, I am sure i will be able to compile these two successfully if i make the names unique in each file. However, I cant change the x,y,z,n,p because they are numerous in these files and I have many more files to work with which have common named functions and variables.

Can anyone please explain it to me what is happening here and how to fix it? I would really like to know what is causing this. I tried reading from previous posts, '[Understanding the origin of a linker duplicate symbol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116188/understanding-the-origin-of-a-linker-duplicate-symbol-error/6116594#6116594) ' but I don't think it is a header related problem.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try adding namespaces?

Comment: @flu You mean add namespaces ( or NS ) in the NS file? My understanding is that NS for respective functions get added _after_ the compilation has succeeded, which is not happening here. Curious to know if NS can be added any other way or if  I am missing something here?

Comment: I meant add namespaces like this, in foo.cpp:   namespace foo { size_t m; ...  }   and in bar.cpp:    namespace bar { size_t m; ... }.  Sorry formatting in comments is a lot less legible.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why global variables are evil.  You declared `n` and `p` in both files as global variables.  You're only allowed one definition of a global variable.

Comment: @flu.. thank you. making the functions and variables static worked for me. Did not try Namespaces yet, but will keep it in mind and will also see how it works in my project. I didnt know of these concepts. Now I understand this better. So thank you for helping.

Answer (score 6):

The example is incomplete, which makes it hard to comment.

But let me make a guess:  you have *globals* in both files and they are visible across both.  That is a design error.  You can either

- make them local to each file if their state is not shared, use `static` for that
- make them shared by declaring one file only and using `extern` in the other.

But the error you quote is different and we don't know anything about your `input::init()`...

Also, I also see nothing related to Rcpp here, so wht add the tag for it?

Comment: `static` did the trick for me. I learned this today itself. Thank you. Accepting  your answer. P.S. coudln't write more elaborated example. But will try better from next time. And Rcpp was added just cause I did not know the origins of the error, so thought the more information I provide, the better.